# imagemagick converted images are grey

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

in our current workflow we are using ImageMagick 6.7 to convert tif images to jp2000 and using bookviewer to display the jp2000 pictures, however the converted images always are more grey in color than the tif files, I have tried imageMagick's type option parameter TrueColor and colorspace sRGB together and seperately in the commandline and it still did not fix the issue. here's the command I'm using to convert in batch:

```
    mogrify -format jp2 -colorspace sRGB -type TrueColor -path {file}
```

here's the verbose information of the tif file info,

```
Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3416x4488+0+0
  Resolution: 400x400
  Print size: 8.54x11.22
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: LSB
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 1-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 1 (1)
      mean: 0.762666 (0.762666)
      standard deviation: 0.425449 (0.425449)
      kurtosis: -0.475339
      skewness: -1.23477
  Colors: 2
  Histogram:
   3638570: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  11692438: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 3416x4488+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    comment: 0030\0060\00001890.tif
    date:create: 2018-12-18T11:09:35-05:00
    date:modify: 2018-12-18T11:09:35-05:00
    signature: 2e4752f9eed1faeea038a7f33c562901502146ecdced65d2955751e549614fb2
    tiff:artist: The Crowley Company
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: min-is-white
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 19
    tiff:software: Kofax standard Multi-Page TIFF Storage Filter v3.03.000
    tiff:timestamp: 2011:05:06 23:45:16
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 1.917MBB
  Number pixels: 15.33MB
  Pixels per second: 102.2MB
  User time: 0.070u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.150
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2017-03-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

and here's the converted jp2 file info

```
Image: 101083016_00009_00004_00119.jp2
  Format: JP2 (JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 3379x4443+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 46.9306x61.7083
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 2/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 3 (1)
      mean: 2.69697 (0.898989)
      standard deviation: 0.904028 (0.301343)
      kurtosis: 5.01231
      skewness: -2.64808
  Colors: 2
  Histogram:
   1516462: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
  13496435: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 3379x4443+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG2000
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-04-04T17:33:24-04:00
    date:modify: 2019-04-04T17:33:24-04:00
    signature: c5a16ea080389f3909f1ca87c4d0cc752b87af8c9fd24ad1a222b94904bf6950
  Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 394 bytes
      Restricted ICC profile describing sRGB-grey
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 364KBB
  Number pixels: 15.01MB
  Pixels per second: 7.082MB
  User time: 1.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:03.120
  Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2017-03-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

can anyone point out to me how I can keep the jp2 color white or which options I should use to prevent the converted jp2000 coming out grey? thanks!

Comment: Post links to one of your input TIF files and output JPG files so we can test and compare. Also note that IM 6.7 is ancient by version and by date is 2 years old. If on Linux, check if there is a more current patch. Currently ImageMagick is at 6.9.10.39.

Comment: here's the jp2000 output https://drive.google.com/file/d/14csP-YQcLI9bUBUAc4r9S-C0SVhyYZ2i/view?usp=sharing 
and here's the tif input file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wsd6t6jo_jVr_r8IhLQ27cHFB7_tLpv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works fine for me on IM 6.9.10.39 Q16 Mac OSX. You do not need -colorspace sRGB. I suspect it is your version of ImageMagick or perhaps you are using Jasper delegate due to an old version of ImageMagick. OpenJpeg was used starting with IM 6.8.8-2 and requires Openjpeg 2.1. Your patch date should be equivalent of 6.9.8-3. But if on Linux, they often do not keep up with enhancement and just patch for security. I cannot say that is true for you. But check to see if  you are using OpenJpeg and what version it is. `convert -list format` should show the version for JP2 at the end of the line

Comment: CONTINUED: also check your version of libtiff. Mine was 4.0.10. Perhaps that needs updating.